# Java thread safety of list

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a List, which is to be used either in thread-safe context or in a non thread-safe one. Which one will it be, is impossible to determine in advance.

In such special case, whenever the list enters non-thread-safe context, I wrap it using

> Collections.synchronizedList(...)

But I don't want to wrap it, if doesn't enter non-thread-safe context. F.e., because list is huge and used intensively.

I've read about Java, that its optimization policy is strict about multi-threading - if you don't synchronize your code correctly, it is not guaranteed to be executed correctly in inter-thread context - it can reorganize code significantly, providing consistency in context of only one thread (see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.3). F.e.,

> op1;
>   op2;
>   op3;

may be reorganized in

> op3;
>   op2;
>   op1;

, if it produces same result (in one-thread context).

Now I wonder, if I

1. fill my list before wrapping it by synchronizedList,
2. then wrap it up,
3. then use by different thread

, - is there a possibility, that different thread will see this list filled only partially or not filled at all? Might JVM postpone (1) till after (3)? Is there a correct and **fast** way to make (big) List being non-thread-safe to become thread-safe?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your list into a synchronized list and it proved too slow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you give your list to another thread by thread-safe means (for example using a synchronized block, a volatile variable or an `AtomicReference`), it is guaranteed that the second thread sees the whole list in the state it was when transferring (or any later state, but not an earlier state).

If you don't change it afterwards, you also don't need your synchronizedList.

---

Edit (after some comments, to backup my claim):

I assume the following:

- we have a volatile variable `list`.

  ```
  volatile List<String> list = null;
  ```
- Thread A:

  1. creates a List L and fills L with elements.
  2. sets `list` to point to L (this means *writes L to `list`*)
  3. does no further modifications on L.

  Sample source:

  ```
  public void threadA() {
     List<String> L = new ArrayList<String>();
     L.add("Hello");
     L.add("World");
     list = l;
  }
  ```
- Thread B:

  1. reads K from `list`
  2. iterates over K, printing the elements.

  Sample source:

  ```
  public void threadB() {
       List<String> K = list;
       for(String s : K) {
           System.out.println(s);
       }
  }
  ```
- All other threads do not touch the list.

Now we have this:

- The actions 1-A and 2-A in Thread A are ordered by [program order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.3) so 1 comes before 2.
- The action 1-B and 2-B in Thread B are ordered by [program order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.3) so 1 comes before 2.
- The action 2-A in Thread A and action 1-B in Thread are ordered by [synchronization order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4), so 2-A comes before 1-B, since

  > A write to a volatile variable (§8.3.1.4) *v* synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of *v* by any thread (where subsequent is defined according to the synchronization order).
- The [happens-before](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5)-order is the transitive closure of the program orders of the individual threads and the synchronization order. So we have:

  1-A  happens-before  2-A  happens-before  1-B  happens-before   2-B

  and thus 1-A happens-before 2-B.
- Finally,

  > If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

So our iterating thread really can see the whole list, and not only some parts of it.
So, transmitting the list with a single volatile variable is sufficient, and we don't need synchronization in this simple case.

---

One more edit (here, since I have more formatting freedom than in the comments) about the program order of Thread A. (I also added some sample Code above.)

From the JLS (section [program order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.3)):

> Among all the inter-thread actions performed by each thread t, the program order
>   of t is a total order that reflects the order in which these actions would be
>   performed according to the intra-thread semantics of t.

So, what are the *intra-thread semantics* of thread A?

Some [paragraphs above](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#60241):

> The memory model determines what values can be read at every point in the program.
>   The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics
>   of that thread, with the exception that the values seen by each read are
>   determined by the memory model. When we refer to this, we say that the program
>   obeys *intra-thread semantics*. Intra-thread semantics are the semantics for
>   single threaded programs, and allow the complete prediction of the behavior of
>   a thread based on the values seen by read actions within the thread. To determine
>   if the actions of thread t in an execution are legal, we simply evaluate the
>   implementation of thread t as it would be performed in a single threaded context,
>   as defined in the rest of this specification.

*The rest of this specification* includes [section 14.2 (Blocks)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.2):

> A block is executed by executing each of the local variable declaration
>   statements and other statements in order from first to last (left to right).

So, the *program order* is indeed the order in which the statements/expressions
are given in the program source code.

Thus, in our example source, the memory actions *create a new ArrayList*, *add "Hello"*, *add "World"*, and *assign to `list`* (the first three consist of more subactions) indeed are in **this program order**.

(The VM does not have to execute the actions in this order, but this *program order* still contributes to the *happens-before* order, and thus to the visibility to other threads.)

Comment: If I declare this List to be volatile, do I not guarantee only the fact, that **reference** to this List is thread safe? I mean, it doesn't guarantee, that references kept inside that list are volatile by cascade...

Comment: @Andrey - the volatile assignment guarantees visibility of everything, including references inside the list.  the important caveat, of course, is that this list _must not_ be modified after the volatile assignment.

Comment: A volatile variable ensures that when one thread reads it, it sees _everything_ that another thread has written before this other thread wrote this value to the volatile variable (not limited to objects reachable from the variable itself - it could be a boolean, even). So make sure that you assign to this volatile variable _after_ filling the list, not before or during.

Comment: @jtahlborn, @Paulo, In this case @Andrey is right about the semantics of the `volatile` keyword. Declaring the variable volatile only ensures that the code always reads the most current reference to the list. In x86 this would only cause a barrier during a write-read (StoreLoad) subsequent reads prior to another write (LoadLoad) won't cause barriers. On the bright side, calling any method on a SynchronizedList will. See, it is the beauty of synchronizing every method call that ensures the contents of the list are current. That seems to be the detail you've missed.

Comment: @Tim Bender: I still think volatile is enough. I added a proof based on the JLS to my answer. Maybe you are considering another case?

Comment: In the simple case that `B` is only interested in reading the `list` contents and `A` promises to never ever edit the `list` contents again?

Comment: @Tim Bender: Yes, see my *assumptions*. When multiple threads are reading and writing, obviously some synchronization is needed between every such action. But this simplificating condition already was in my post and the comments before your one.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is kinda silly, but why do you think, that "1-A and 2-A are ordered by program order"? Well, OK, creation of the list will happen first, but filling it is a separate operation, which is not happens-before-related with 2-A. For thread A there is no difference between executions "first fill list, then 2-A" and "first 2-A, then fill list" - both give same result, and program-order isn't ruined. In fact, by filling the list I do not WRITE to variable "L" or to volatile variable "list" - I only READ from it to get access to inner data structures, which may be not volatile.

Comment: "*Among all the inter-thread actions performed by each thread t, the program order of t is a total order that reflects the order in which these actions would be performed according to the intra-thread semantics of t.*" - the *program order* is the order in which the actions are written in the code of the thread, not regarding reorderings. (It does not have to be the same order as executed, but it still induces a *happens-before* relation.)

Comment: I don't see, how you made implication from this **be performed according to the intra-thread semantics of t** to this **the program order is the order in which the actions are written in the code of the thread**.I understand, that **synchronization order** respects **program order**, but this **program order** in java has a special meaning, relaxed comparing to usual programmer's. I still don't see the rule you rely on to reason, that **l.fill()** wouldn't be reordered with 2-A operation since their reordering for inter-thread semantics is legal - both just READING l, not of them WRITING it.

Comment: @Andrey: See my latest additions to the answer: program order in fact is what the programmer has written (not necessary what the VM later does).

Comment: @Paŭlo "The rest of this specification includes section 14.2 (Blocks): ..." By this citation you imply, that reordering of operations never occur in java? Well, that can't be true - check inter-thread anomalies (17.3)! That is why reliable program order is only that, which is __sequentially consistent__, which ensures only that intra-thread reads-writes of variables to happen in _correct_ order, where correctness is a computational correctness. And on top of that builds synchronization order, but intra-thread __sequentially consistency__ doesn't need to know about that, afaik...

Comment: No, I say that reordering does not effect the **program order**. Reordering does occur *after* the definition of program order. And reordering can only cause inter-thread anomalies, when there is no *happens-before* relationship between actions (on different threads). In our case, the volatile variable creates a *happens-before* relationship between all reads and writes of the list elements.

Comment: @Paŭlo _"the volatile variable creates a happens-before relationship between all reads and writes of the list elements"_ - by what rule???? Write to volatile var "list" establishes only one relation - a synchronizes-with relation between A and B, where A is writing reference to our List into "list" variable; and B - any subsequent read of reference to a List from variable "list" by any thread.

Comment: No other happens-before relation is established, no relation between filling the list and reading it by other thread, because volatile secures only REFERENCE to a list, not any adjacent references, occuring inside the List!

Comment: @Andrey: The volatile variable establishs a *synchronizes-with* relation between A-2 and B-1, yes. The *being in the same thread* facts establish *program-order* relationships between A-1 and A2 and between B-1 and B-2. Each of this three induces a *happens-before* relationship, so A-1 *happens-before* A-2, A-2 *happens-before* B-1 and B-1 *happens-before* B-2. And then we have the fact that *happens-before* is transitive, which means that A-1 *happens-before* B-2, too. (All of this is written in the answer, too.) I don't know how to explain it, if this is not yet understandable.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5 : It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.

Comment: That's why [anomalies are possible](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.3), that's why I asked question here - the program order is not guaranteed.

Comment: The program order does not guarantee execution order, yes. But it still implies an *happens-before* order, and together with the *synchronization order* of the two accesses of the `list` variable, it guarantees that the adds of the first thread **are visible** by the reads on the second thread (whether or not they are executed in this order).

Comment: @Paŭlo I've found [some description](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_java_5.shtml) of _volatile_, which I trust enough. After all, JLS occur to me be written in too complex language - it's reasoning is still unclear to me. Thanks for your efforts and sorry for being slow to understand. =)

Answer (score 4):

If you fill your list and then wrap it in the same thread, you'll be safe.

However there are several things to bear in mind:

1. `Collections.synchronizedList()` only guarantees you a low-level thread safety. Complex operations, like `if ( !list.contains( elem ) ) list.add( elem );` will still need custom synchronization code.
2. Even this guarantee is void if any thread can obtain a reference to the original list. Make sure this doesn't happen.
3. Get the functionality right first, then you can start worrying about synchronization being too slow. I very rarely encountered code where the speed of Java synchronization was a serious factor.

**Update:** I'd like to add a few excerpts from the JLS to hopefully clarify matters a bit.

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

This is why filling the list and then wrapping it in the same thread is a safe option. But more importantly:

> This is an extremely strong guarantee for programmers. Programmers do not need to reason about reorderings to determine that their code contains data races. Therefore they do not need to reason about reorderings when determining whether their code is correctly synchronized. Once the determination that the code is correctly synchronized is made, the programmer does not need to worry that reorderings will affect his or her code.

The message is clear: make sure that your program, executed in the order which you wrote your code in, doesn't contain data races, and don't worry about reordering.

Comment: Can you prove this statement? Note that creation of synchronized list is not synchronized.

Comment: @axtavt Note my opening words: "IF you fill your list and then wrap it in the same thread". There's nothing to prove really.

Comment: How do you know synchronizedList() guarantees happens-before relation? My guess is that simple walking through the list would be enough to convince JVM optimizer to complete all pending operations to it's structure, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @biziclop: The fact that filling the unsynchronized list _happens-before_ subsequent accesses to the synchronized list need to be proven. As far as I understand, `Collections.synchronizedList()` doesn't gurantee it.

Comment: yes, @axtavt is somewhat right.  the newly created, wrapped list must be properly "published" to other threads (e.g. assigned to final member var, assigned to volatile ref, accessed within sync block).  once properly published, everything else in the answer is correct.

Comment: @jtahlborn If you're really paranoid, you can do that. But then I would create the synchronized list first, then use it to fill all the elements. I highly doubt the performance difference is noticeable.

Comment: @biziclop - i don't understand what you are saying.  proper "publishing" of the list is an orthogonal issue to the actual thread-safe usage of the list.  it's not paranoid, it's "working code" vs. "broken code".

Comment: @jtahlborn Sorry, I simply misunderstood what you meant by publishing.

Comment: @jtahlborn, you're wrong about "proper publishing". The synchronized list is as an object representing a collection never changes. There is no need to make it volatile, declaring final isn't mandatory (though probably doesn't hurt), nor does it need to be first assigned in a sync block or any other paranoid thing you could think of. There is no magic to synchronized list, it is simply a delegate list implementation in which every method is synchronized. The reference created by `Collections.synchronizedList` must be used for all accesses to the original list once it is shared, but that's it.

Comment: @Tim Bender Now I'm completely confused as to what "proper publishing" is supposed to mean. :)

Comment: @biziclop, if you had to use such a vague and meaningless term as "proper publishing" then I'd say in this specific case it means to ensure that only references to the synchronized list are allowed to escape from the code block which initializes the list contents.

Comment: @Tim Bender But I'd venture a guess, I think what @jtahlborn meant was a situation when a synchronized list is already in use by several threads and you want to replace it with a newly created one. To avoid some threads working on the old list, while others on the new, you have to "publish" them in an atomic manner.

Comment: @biziclop, I have my doubts, and that would be tangential to the original question.

Comment: @TimBender. By publish I am sure he simply means the assignment of the list field is visible to all threads after said write

Comment: @biziclop Please, consider case discussed here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922173/java-thread-safety-of-list/4922613#4922613). You quoted: _If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)._ - here term "program order" has a special meaning, and it concerns about "write to a VAR must happen before read in a programmed order".

Comment: Now, if I "publish" my list, I do ensure only that REFERENCE to it is WRITTEN and READ in a synchronized way. There is no guarantee, that references used inside the list are volatile. WRITING them doesn't need WRITING the reference to the whole list. **x = new List(); volatile y = x; x.fill(...);** <- in this program there's no difference for PROGRAM ORDER, whether **"y = x"** happens before **"x.fill(...)"** or not in context of single thread, and PROGRAM ORDER is concerned about only single thread context.

Comment: @Andrey If you read my answer carefully, you'll see that this is completely different scenario to what I referred to. The correct way of doing it is: Create list -> Fill list -> Wrap it in sunchronized list -> Pass the synchronized list reference to every thread. This assumes that your list will have to be modified later by those threads.  If this is not the case, you can use the other solution that doesn't require synchronized lists but doesn't allow further modifications either.

Comment: @biziclop I still believe, that "_If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)._" isn't the case for "_This is why filling the list and then wrapping it in the same thread is a safe option._", because term "program order" has a special (relaxed) meaning in specification you rely on.

Comment: As for my example **"x = new List(); volatile y = x; x.fill(...);"** - I just wanted to show, that for JVM it would sound the same as **"x = new List(); x.fill(...); volatile y = x;"** - thus I don't see guarantees, that **fill(...)** operation would happen in time - in "program order" in our programmers usual meaning, not in java's special meaning for program order. And here it doesn't matter, be it **"volatile y = x;"** or **"y = Collections.synchronizedList()"**, because both suffer same issue.

Comment: @Andrey Fair enough, although I have to point out that the specification I rely on is the only relevant specification. But you're free to believe what you wish, I'm not going to argue. If you want to make your life as miserable as possible by worrying about things the JLS explicitly says you don't have to, fine.

Comment: @biziclop By questioning here I hoped to see logically reasoned answer, not a blind religious belief in some citations filled with words, that "look like somehow fit the context" and containing key words "don't worry"... As I said before, there is no statements in JLS that would state there is a synchronizes-with relationship between list.fill(...) and further inter-thread operations with it wrapped (or published in other way). Nor there I see prove of happens-before relations. These are matters of original question - If you answered some other question, then you probably got to a wrong topic.

Comment: @biziclop, assuming you pass the wrapped list w/o issuing any memory fence (aka happens before stuff), for example via non volatile variable write. The 2nd thread accessing the list is not guaranteed to see the proper content. `Collections.synchronizeXXX` doesn't do anything special, just wraps the object w/ another one whose methods are all synchronized. Calling size() on the wrapped list *before the assignment* will do the trick (writing anything volatile to issue the memory fence). Technically speaking, it's very rare in practice to see handling objects w/o volatile semantics, though.

Comment: @bestsss I see what you mean now. Calling `size()` isn't enough though, you'll have to query an element as well. (At least in `ArrayList`, in `LinkedList` you'd probably have to iterate across all of them.) But it's even cleaner if you create the list first, create an empty synchronized list and then call `addAll()`.

Comment: @biziclop, calling size on the Collections.synchronizeXXX() i meant, if unclear (to have the memory fence)

Comment: @bestsss `List l = new SomeList(); l.fill(...); volatile list_forall = Collections.synchronizeList(l); list_forall.size();` If I understand correctly, this might be enough, if getting last actual value of `size()` requires all operations with structure of the List be finished. Though there are 2 problems here: (i) some List implementations might use fixed size array, whose size isn't functionally dependent on List structure. That's where iterating through all list elements might be required, I guess; or where to use biziclop's solution (create an empty synchronized list and then call addAll())

Comment: (ii) second problem I'm not sure about: may JVM optimizer postpone the `list_forall.size();` call? I'm not using it anywhere, so _lazy_ behaviour ... I would be more confident, if I wrote `System.out.println(list_forall.size());`, since it _requires_ size value to be output. Or is `list_forall.size();` really enough?

Comment: @Andrey, if you have **volatile**  `list_forall=Collections.synchronizeList(l)` you do not need ANYTHING else at all. Everything else *before* that operator (assignment) must be ordered properly (by java spec). Calling `size()` would be needed *only if* list_forall was not volatile. JVM can optimize calling size() and not call it but it cannot optimize the needed happen-before, so even optimized it must issue the memory fence which is what's needed. Note: memory fences ensure proper order (which is actually happen-before semantics), so all the elements are actually in the list.

Comment: @Andrey, bottomline: `List l = new SomeList(); l.fill(...); volatile list_forall = Collections.synchronizeList(l);` follows java spec. and it's thread safe. That's all necessary

Comment: @bestsss Unfortunately `size` is stored as a separate field in most list implementations, so that would not entirely guarantee that the contents are there too. Although in practice I don't thnink you'd find a VM implementation where it doesn't.

Comment: @bestsss Excuse me, but I can't find in jSpecs anything about memory fences. It's said about volatile variables, that they guard only reads/writes to variables they describe. On the other hand, there is (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5) `It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.`, and there also are anomalies described in 17.3.

Comment: Why are you so sure that `volatile list_forall=Collections.synchronizeList(l);` provides a memory fence?

Comment: @Andrey, memory fences are part the implementation details to ensure the order of execution is preserved (happens-before stuff), basically that's how volatile is implemented. In this particular case: assigning to the `volatile list_forall` ensures (that's according to the spec) that any subsequent reads (of it) will happen after all the operations before the assignment (i.e. the memory will be visible to the rest of CPUs).  You should (and will) not see java spec mentioning fences, that's the point of the abstraction.

Comment: @biziclop, you access size (or it can be just count the size or whatever) via sync. block (monitorEnter/monitorExit) and that's what takes care; size() can practically be `return Integer.MAX_VALUE` and it will make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

If the traverses happens more often than writing I'd look into [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in
>   which all mutative operations (add,
>   set, and so on) are implemented by
>   making a fresh copy of the underlying
>   array.

Comment: This solution is kinda "fat". It can't be fast with big lists.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) (and the likes) are implemented to be thread safe & not synchronized. The mechanism does not introduce synchronization, but if one is needed, it handles it gracefully.