# can i synchronize 2 different methods? java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have some trouble with the use of the synchronized keyword in java. I do understand the part where threads get locks on methods or code blocks but I dont know how to use it in the following example.

I have got 2 different threads (Thread A and Thead B) and a Class1 that holds a list witch contains instances of Class2. The Class1.methodA() that gets called by threadA modifies the information in the list. The Class1.methodB() that gets called by threadB only uses the information in the list.

I concluded that problems that i am having in my program occur when Thread A is modifying the data in the list while Thread B is using it.

Should i create a synchronized method inside Class1 which than calls MethodA or MethodB (seems redundant to me). Or can the thread get a lock just on the specific instance of Class2 that is being modified?

I am sorry for any bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Have both methods syncrhonize on the list:

```
methodA()
{
   synchronized(list) 
   {
      ... use the list, no one else can touch it
   }
   ... do other stuff.
}
```

same for methodB()

[More info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: thanks. So the Thread does get a lock on the list in stead of a lock on the code block?

Comment: Yes. In this case, you are not worried about 2 threads making calls to the same method, but two methods accessing the same shared variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a explanation about the threading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922173/java-thread-safety-of-list)

Well, back to your question. You can actually just use the synchronize on your list and do the reading or adding in this synchronize block.

```
synchronized(yourList)
{
    // do something
}
```

Otherwise I guess you can use the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` ([API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)) from the `java.util.concurrent` package. But this is really costly, because it makes always a fresh copy of the underlying array.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> myArrayList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

myArrayList .add("Stackoverflow");

Iterator<String> iterator = myArrayList .iterator(); 

while (iterator.hasNext())
   System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Another method would be to use the `synchronizedList`

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

But you still need the synchronized block in the end. The add and remove methods itself are atomic and thread safe, but iterating over the list is not.